# AS3 rotate start speed then slow down over time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, rotation

I got this code that makes my object rotate continuously

```
movieClip_2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_RotateContinuously_2);

function fl_RotateContinuously_2(event:Event)
{
    movieClip_2.rotation += 100;

}
```

How can i get this object to slow down over say 5 sec from 100 to 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fps:Number = stage.frameRate;
var step:int = 100;
var minStep:int = 10;
var time:Number = 5;
var increment:Number = (step - minStep) / (time * fps);

movieClip_2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_RotateContinuously_2);

function fl_RotateContinuously_2(event:Event)
{
    movieClip_2.rotation += step;
    step -= increment;
    step = Math.max(minStep, step);
}
```